# Is there a way to create a filter for CancellationToken for all actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create an ASP.NET Core WebApi Service where every actions supports a CancellationToken without explicitly implementing it with a parameter.

I don't want to do this for every action:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    return await DoStuffAsync(token);
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return await DoStuffAsync(_contextManager.Token);
}
```

Where `_contextManager` extracts the CancellationToken from the action.
Would this be possible with a custom `IActionFilter` or another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CancellationToken` passed into actions is bound using [`CancellationTokenModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs#L28), which uses `HttpContext.RequestAborted` as the value. You can use this yourself, directly, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return await DoStuffAsync(HttpContext.RequestAborted);
}
```